# Время на проход ледовых полей

Tags: алгоритм

На собеседовании дали задачку для решения на любом языке за **1 час**. Я не сумел уложиться в 1 час. :( Очень бы хотелось узнать решения коллег и время решения ими задачи.

> Группа из n кораблей должна пройти через ледовые поля. В группе один ледокол, за которым может идти только один корабль без ледовой защиты и один корабль с ней, поэтому тактика прохода через поля такая: ледокол проводит один из кораблей без защиты и один корабль с ней, потом защита ставится на один из кораблей и ледокол возвращается с ним.  Время прохода пары определяется кораблем с наименьшей скоростью.
>
> Требуется найти наименьшее время, за которое группа пройдет ледовые поля.
>
> Исходные данные: n - количество кораблей, v[n] - массив времен на прохождение кораблями полей.

Пример: 4 корабля. Время прохода: 1, 10, 5, 2. Общее время: 17. Ниже движение кораблей.

```
1 2 5 10   ||              = 0
5 10       ->   1 2        = 2
1 5 10     <-   2          = 3
1          ->   5 10 2     = 13
1 2        <-   5 10       = 15
           ->   1 2 5 10   = 17
```

Comment: А обратная скорость ледокола тоже определяется скоростью последнего корабля или как?

Comment: Мм, а в чём хитрость? - я с утра не въезжаю =D Сложить да и все дела. Тока что в последний раз ледоколу обратно идти не придётся. Но скорость возвращения будет всегда одна и та же вне зависимости от предыдущего корабля. И скорость кораблей от порядка не зависит. И пары уравнений нет, из которых можно было бы найти время прохода ледокола самого по себе. Хотя оценить достаточно просто - меньше половины времени самой быстрой пары.

Comment: что значит за минимальное время ты тут как не крути быстрее чем за время v[i] (i=1,n) ты не проплывешь, точнее i-ый корабль, так что мой вариант был бы просуммировать все элементы.

Comment: @byte Наверное, Вы что-то напутали в условиях задачи. В таком виде она слишком простая :)

Comment: Странная задачка. Получается, что за раз проходят два корабля + ледокол. Итого пример решаем так: группируем (10,5) и (1,2). Делаем так, потому что это всяко выгоднее, чем все по отдельности или вариант (2,10)+(5,1) или (1,10)+(2,5). Итого получатся 10+2 минуты+время возврата ледокола (а оно какое!?). Т.е. первое действие - отсортировать массив времени по порядку. Затем разбить на пары из соседних элементов. При этом может остаться один непарный корабль, который пойдет в одиночку с ледоколом. А могут все спариться.

Comment: ты уверен что пример правильный?

Comment: Уверен. Один корабль должен вернуться с ледовой защитой. То есть 10 и 5 пройдут за 10, а потом вернется тот, что 5 или 10. Это уже будет 15 или 20!

Comment: Ну вот 10 это время прохода чем больше время чем меньше скорость, а значит нам надо что бы быстрее пройти что бы один из кораблей возвращался быстрее, а значит корабль с минимальным временем 1
получается. Сначала идёт 10 и 1 возвращается 1, 10+1 время уже 11 потом идёт 5 и 1 возвращается 1 время 11+5+1 уже 17 а потом ещё должны пройти 2 и 1 за время 2 это 19 так что за 17 ну никак не уложимся

Comment: v - это время в одну сторону, а не в обе, как я писал прежде.

Comment: Есть, есть решение, при котором уложимся в 17. Я пока его не скажу. :)

Comment: Ну вот скажи какое тогда будет яснее

Comment: @gecube Если я правильно понял задачу, так нельзя, там надо защиту таскать. Поэтому одно судно будет возвращаться с ледоколом.

Comment: Тогда вообще не понимаю смысла таскать защиту.

Comment: > Тогда вообще не понимаю смысла таскать защиту.

смысл ее таскать только в условии задачи.

p.s. это какая-то нереальная задача. в реальной жизни любой корабль будет быстрее ледокола. а значит чтоб провести все понадобится время:  
`(n-2) * min (v);`

Comment: Я что-то не пойму, а почему в примере 5 10  ->  1 2  = 2 а не 1? Ведь время прохода пары определяется кораблем с наименьшей скоростью. Объясните плиз :)

Comment: Кстати, сама задача в частном виде (с цифрами 1, 2, 5, 10) была в игрушке "Космические рейнджеры". Формулировка была чуть другой: надо было перевозить четырех братьев через реку в двухместной лодке.

Comment: @Sever, потому что:

> Время прохода пары определяется кораблем с наименьшей скоростью.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogo, я наверно туплю, но вроде как 1 меньше 2-х. А если наименьшей скоростью то логичнее 1 ведь. Т.е если (5 10 -> 1 2) т.е корабли со скорость 1 и 2 перебрались, у одного скорость 1 а у другого 2 то разве корабль с наименьшей скоростью не тот у которого скорость 1?

Comment: Это не скорость, это время за которое корабль проходит поле. Соответственно, чем меньше число, тем выше скорость.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правильную тактику расписал [[@Fiztex](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex): сначала выбираем пару самых быстрых кораблей - они будут таскать экран обратно. Далее алгоритм следующий:

1. Переправляем пару быстрых
2. Если все корабли перевезены, то задача выполнена, иначе идем к п.3
3. Первого быстрого (любого из пары быстрых) возвращаем
4. Переправляем пару самых медленных
5. Второго быстрого (оставшегося из пары быстрых) возвращаем
6. Переходим к п.1

Соответственно, что бы рассчитать минимальное время, можно сделать следующее:

- Отсортировать все корабли по скорости
- Разбить все корабли по парам начиная с самых медленных (`pairs`)
- Выделить из каждой пары самый медленный корабль - это и будет скорость пары
- Первая пара - это перевозчики щита (`fast_ships`)
- Соответственно конечная формула будет: `sum(max(pair)) + ((sum(fast_ships) + max(fast_ships)) * (len(pairs) - 1))`

Пример программы на питоне:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: %s ship1 ship2 shipN' % sys.argv[0])
    exit(1)

try:
    ships = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect input')
    exit(1)

ships.sort()

fast_ships, ships = ships[:2], ships[2:]
pairs = [ships[max(0, i-2):i] for i in range(len(ships), 0, -2)]
best_time = sum([max(pair) for pair in pairs]) + max(fast_ships) + (sum(fast_ships) + max(fast_ships)) * (len(pairs))

print('Best time: %d' % best_time)
```

.

```
$ python ships.py 10 5 2 1
Best time: 17
```

PS Примечательно, что точно такая же задача была в космических рейнджерах :) Даже цифры в примере те-же самые.

Comment: Не всегда так:

    $ python ships.py 1 101 102 103
    Best time: 407

правильное минимальное время будет 309.

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется, что надо балансировать между двумя тактиками, на каждом шаге, выбирая оптимальную:

Тактика 1:
Переправляем сначала два самых быстрых, соответственно один из них возвращаем. Затем переправляем два самых медленных, возвращаем второй из самых быстрых. Далее опять переправляем оба самых быстрых, один из них возвращаем. Далее переправляем два самых медленных из оставшихся, возвращаем второй из самых быстрых и т.д.

Тактика 2:
Переправляем самый быстрый с самым медленным, самый быстрый возвращаем. Далее снова самый быстрый с самым медленным из оставшихся и т.д.

Строго пока не доказал.

А вообще можно в любом случае написать решение на основе динамического программирования, хотя оно, судя по всему, будет далеко не оптимальным.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос актуальность утратил, по-видимому, но алгоритм может быть полезен кому-то

```
  function iceFieldTime(mas) {
    // Вырожденные случаи
    if (mas.length == 0) return 0;
    if (mas.length == 1) return mas[0];

    // Сортируем корабли по времени
    mas.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });

    // Самые быстрые корабли - "драйверы", driver1 - быстрый, driver2 - медленный
    var driver1 = mas.shift();
    var driver2 = mas.shift();

    // Время на перегон драйверов через поле
    var time = driver2;

    // В случае нечетного числа кораблей добавляем время на перегон быстрого драйвера на исходную и обратно через поле с самым быстрым из оставшихся кораблей
    if (mas.length % 2 == 1) time += mas.shift() + driver1;

    // Осталось перегнать четное число кораблей, перегоняем их по парам
    while (mas.length > 0) {
      // Перегоняем быстрый драйвер с защитой на исходную позицию
      if (mas.length > 0) time += driver1;

      // Добавляем время на перегон самого медленного
      var ship1 = mas.pop();
      time += ship1;

      // В зависимости от минимального времени, 
      // либо перегоняем второй корабль пары с самым медленным 
      // и потом два раза медленный драйвер за быстрым (driver2 * 2),
      // либо перегоняем второй корабль с быстрым драйвером (driver1 + ship2)
      var ship2 = mas.pop();
      time += driver2 * 2 < driver1 + ship2 ? driver2 * 2 : driver1 + ship2;
    };
    return time;
  }
```

Comment: Вот это похоже на правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

[[[[@Fiztex](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex) предложил две тактики и правильный ответ для произвольных скоростей будет их комбинацией.

Надо исходить из того за какое время можно перевезти два корабля (при этом ледокол и броня должны оказаться в исходной точке), т.е. задача делится на перевоз пар самых медленных кораблей. NB: Если останется один медленный корабль (плюс два быстрых), он перевозится одним способом - с помощью самого быстрого. Два быстрых перевозятся за одну ходку.

Перевезти два корабля можно двумя способами, один из них будет оптимальным, его и надо выбрать. Пусть у нас есть 4 корабля в начальной точке. a,b,c,d - их время поездки, отсортированы они так: a<b<c<d. Тогда для них будет следующие варианты (см. ответ [[[[@Fiztex](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex)](/users/1590/fiztex)):

1. Возим два меньших, с меньшим возвращаемся, потом два больших, с оставшимся меньшим возвращаемся. Время поездки будет равно a+2*b+d.
2. Возим меньший и больший, с меньшим возвращаемся, опять меньший и больший, меньший возвращаем. Время поездки будет равно 2*a+c+d.

Два медленных корабля перевезены. Мы оказались в начале следующей подзадачи. 
Ну и в начале каждой подзадачи выбираем минимум из двух времён.

Очевидно если 2*b<a+c, то будет выбрана первая стратегия, в противном случае вторая.

**UPD** Код.

```
var v = [1,2,5,7,10,100];
v.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
var result = 0;
var i;    
for (i = v.length - 1; i > 2; i -= 2) {
    result += Math.min(2 * v[0] + v[i - 1] + v[i], v[0] + 2 * v[1] + v[i]);
}
if (i == 2) {
    result += v[0] + v[2];
}
result += v[1];
alert(result); // 119
```

Comment: > Очевидно ...

здесь очевидно только то, что коллективный ум сильнее ума отдельно взятых личностей

Comment: Согласен, припозднился с ответом. В свое время пропустил просто.
Но все же для произвольных времен и количества кораблей верный алгоритм не назвали.

Answer (score 1):

Fiztex, считаю, что тактика 2 действительно верная. Предлагаю доказательство.

### "Туда"

Так как в любом случае придется переправить все корабли, то суммарное время "туда" будет никак не меньше просто суммы подолжительностей для всех кораблей (с поправкой на скорость ледокола разумеется: связка со скоростным кораблём всё равно не может двигаться быстрее ледокола). При этом ясно, что минимизировать время "туда" действительно возможно: из двух кораблей кроме ледокола оставлять на той стороне следует более медленный, в этом случае он больше нигде нас не затормозит.

### "Обратно"

Теперь становится ясно, что как-то улучшить общее время можно именно здесь. Задача путешествия "обратно" - в наименьшее время вернуть ледовую защиту для следующего рейса. Понятно, что наименьшее время будет, если скорость корабля, несущего защиту, будет наибольшей.

**Итак**, тактика действительно проста: ледокол и самый быстрый корабль по очереди перевозят оставшиеся. Можно даже указать суммарное время при этом:

```
T = Sum(i:=1..n-1; min(t;v[i])) + (n-1)*min(t;v[0]), где
```

t - время ледокола
v[0] - время самого быстрого корабля (просто для удобства, пусть он будет первым в массиве)

Comment: В качестве индикаторов кораблей их время. Сначала идёт 10 и 1 возвращается 1, 10+1 время уже 11 потом идёт 5 и 1 возвращается 1 время 11+5+1 уже 17 а потом ещё должны пройти 2 и 1 за время 2 это 19. Алгоритм не подходит, тут не всё так просто.

Comment: Тактика 2 в общем случае не является верной. Например, корабли: 1, 2, 100, 101, 102. Выигрывает тактика 1.

Comment: Мда..не сразу осознал задачу. Действительно, в таком случае не всё так просто.
Что касается двух указанных тактик, есть мысли. В тактике 1 лишний раз переправляется *второй по скорости* корабль и *он же* потом лишний раз возвращается; в тактике 2 *самый скоростной* корабль делает дополнительный рейс для переправы *предпоследнего по скорости*. Из сказанного вытекает предположение: если время *первого* и *предпоследнего* в сумме больше удвоенного времени *второго*, то следует применять на этом шаге тактику 1, иначе тактику 2. Если здесь вообще применим жадный алгоритм, то это наверняка критерий

Answer (score 1):

Не обращайте внимания на переменные функций, моя теория такая, 3 корабля проходят поле, при этом время в любом случае определяется кораблем с наименьшей скоростью, обратно едут 2 корабля, вот здесь второй корабль либо быстрый либо нет, поэтому для обратной пути определяем корабль с наибольшей скоростью так как надо вычислить наименьшее возможное время. Потом берем следующий корабль и считаем снова. По моему не важно в каком порядке брать корабли из списка, можно по очереди...

```
function min(v[1],v[2],v[3]) {
    if(v[1] + v[2] > v[2] + v[3]) {
        if(v[2] > v[3]) {
            return v[3];
        }
        else {
            return v[2];
        }
    }
    else {
        if(v[1] > v[2]) {
            return v[3];
        }
        else {
            return v[2];
        }
    }    
}

function big(v[1],v[2],v[3]) {
    if(v[1] + v[2] > v[2] + v[3]) {
        if(v[1] > v[2]) {
            return v[1];
        }
        else {
            return v[2];
        }
    }
    else {
        if(v[2] > v[3]) {
            return v[2];
        }
        else {
            return v[3];
        }
    }    
}

total= 0;

for (i = 1; i < n.length; i = i + 1) {
    summa = v[i] + v[i + 1] + v[i + 2];
    min =  min(v[i],v[i + 1],v[i + 2]); 
    big = big((v[i],v[i + 1],v[i + 2]);
    middle = summa - (min + big);
    TimeForOneTeam = big + middle;
    total = total + (TimeForOneTeam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в задаче именно такое условие:

```
    В группе один ледокол, за которым может идти только один корабль без ледовой защиты и один корабль с ней...
```

То, думаю, тут нет особого "размаха" для поиска наиболее верной тактики - здесь она одна - та, которую вы описали. А вот если бы можно было, например, ледоколу вести за собой два защищенных корабля, а потом забирать у них броню и возвращаться за незащищенными, то тут бы уже было поинтересней( и побыстрее ). Еще было бы интереснее, если можно было бы вести за собой более двух кораблей.

---

А вообще, зачем ледоколу гонять туда-сюда - ведь лед-то после первого его прохода "туда" уже расколот, а, следовательно, по расколу уже в обратную сторону можно пускать простые корабли с защитой(точнее один корабль, который шел за ледоколом с защитой) =)

Comment: > а, следовательно, по расколу уже в обратную сторону можно пускать простые корабли

очень очень сомневаюсь в этом. вы вообще задумывались почему только 2 корабля могут идти вслед за ледоколом? первый ледокол. второй корабль без защиты (т.к. ледокол уже растолкал все что можно). а вот третий корабль идет уже с защитой. и не просто так, а потому что лед реально уже начинает закрывать проход и есть риск повреждения корпуса.

p.s. вообще задача про сферических кораблей в вакууме. уверен ледокол самый медленный. более медленные суда просто не смогут пройти, - лед будет замерзать быстрее